# How can I get the pval working with percentages considering a table with NA values and data essentially constant (100% or 0%?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, percentage, p-value, hypothesis-test

I am trying to get the pval from a bigdata table (700 observations and 6 variables). I can't calculate the p values due to repeated values of some percetanges (100% or 0%)

The table more or less represent my doubt. What can I do to get my p values at least in the rows that do not display repeated values?

```
b<-cbind(c(100,50,20),c(100,49,19),c(100,48,18),c(100,47,17), c(100,NaN, 16))

pval<-apply(b, 1, function(x) t.test(x[1:2], x[3:4], alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = T))
```

Error in t.test.default(x[1:2], x[3:4], alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = T) : 
  data are essentially constant

Comment: i guess you should not do a t.test on percentages? In any case, using the example you provide, i don't get an error. you can wrap the t.test around try()

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the data. Now is corrected

Comment: thanks. you tried using pval<-apply(b, 1, function(x)try(t.test(...)))?

Comment: With try I get the same outcome.

Comment: yes.. you get an error. But you should also get a pval list. the entries that throw an error have "error.."

Comment: Thank you! I just did that and removed the error row and now it works! Thank you!